# How to implement case expression in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I am trying to implement below SQL in SSIS expression:

```
CASE 
    WHEN TimeZone_No = '-' THEN 
     0 
    ELSE 
        TimeZone_No 
END;
```

Below SSIS Expression is not working:

```
TimeZone_No == '-' ? 0 : TimeZone_No
```

Comment: for me I will try to use DriveColumn and Script task to do this.

Comment: Can you give me some example or link?

Comment: take a look for this. seems no need driveColumn now, https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-script-component-as-transformation/

Comment: Always post the error message you get. The problem gets a lot clearer to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need double quotes to delimit strings in SSIS expressions.

```
TimeZone_No == "-" ? "0" : TimeZone_No
```

Make sure that both sides of the result of the ternary operator match in their data type (`0` with `TimeZone_No` in this case), or else SSIS will squeak.

Comment: Based on the sql code it looks like result is numeric not string

Comment: @Hadi That's what I thought at first too, but then I saw that its the same `TimeZone_No` that's being compared to a hyphen. We can leave the OP to check the correct data type.

Answer (score 0):

Check your data types looks like you are checking a string then trying to put 0 (integer) or string, try changing 0 to a string by adding quotes ''

```
TimeZone_No == ''-'' ? ''0'' : TimeZone_No
```

You need 0 to match whatever the format of TimeZone_No is.
Hope this helps.